# Rewrite a parameter into url (example.com?url=/about-us into example.com/about-us)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, silverstripe

I have some URLs generated by a CMS (SilverStripe CMS) that I wish to rewrite.
For some reason it's possible to set a URL like by appending a `?url=` to the query string.

So `example.com?url=/about-us` and `example.com/about-us` gives the same page.
You can even do `example.com/some-page/?url=/about-us` and you will still get the about us page.

So: How do I rewrite any URL that contains the parameter "url" into `domain.tld` + the value of the URL paramater? (`example.com?url=/about-us` and `example.com/some-page/?url=/about-us` and so on into `example.com/about-us`).

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /[^\?]*\?url=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [L,R=301]
```

This will take any request with a `url=<something>` query string param, completely ignore the URI, and redirect the browser to `/<something>` and append whatever query string happens to be after.